# Retrieve the 3rd node in a 5 node deep system

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get the names of the sections in my Firebase database and add it to a arraylist, but it only returns null.

[image: Firebase Node]

**This is my code:**

```
   mSectionReference = database.getReference().child("/apartments/").child("/B3/").child("/sections/");
    ValueEventListener sectionListner = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d("sections", "onDataChange");

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Log.d("sections", "snapshot exists" );

                for (DataSnapshot sectionSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (sectionSnapshot != null) {
                        Section section = sectionSnapshot.getValue(Section.class);
                        Log.d("sections", "Section created: "  + section.getName());

                    } else
                        Log.d("sections", "sections null");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            Log.w("failedSnap", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    };
    mSectionReference.addValueEventListener(sectionListner);
```

And this is the result of the logcat:

```
onDataChange
snapshot exists
Section created: null
Section created: null
```

Comment: Include Section object implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I found that even though that there is a element in the path, it doesn't mean that there is a "object" there.

I implemented a new hashmap that saves the name of the section as a key and value, making the structure look like this: 
[image: firebase database strcture]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change this line of code:

```
mSectionReference = database.getReference().child("/apartments/").child("/B3/").child("/sections/");
```

with

```
mSectionReference = database.getReference().child("apartments").child("B3").child("sections");
```

The slashes are not needed when you pass the child name as an argument.